# Is it possible to reverse the next and previous keyboard navigation in this example?

Tags: javascript

I am creating this html design on an online software called visme. It is a software that helps create interactive infographics something like canva and allows for a simple Html download.Yey.

My question is: is it possible to reverse the functions of the navigation key board buttons that navigate through the pages in the code generated by visme that I download?

For example, now the right keyboard key takes you to the next page while the left keyboard key takes you to the previous page. Is it possible to reverse that where by the left key takes you to the next page while the right key takes you to the previous page?

Here is a link to the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RrslmElWNq57C5W9lyJuWJRIAlGSX5Fi/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely do that.
jQuery has a predefined keys to their particual value suppose

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    $("#showroom").animate({
      left: "-=980"
    });
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    $("#showroom").animate({
      left: "+=980"
    });
  }
});
```

So left key on the keyboard has a value 37 and that for right is 39.

What you can do is change these value in your jQuery.js file.
Refer to the attached jquery.js file from your drive link.

[image]